# Potential CSS scroll snap bug in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, scroll-snap

Please check [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/NeXTs/pen/abBwXVw). The problem is described there. There is also a demo. I've tested it on Mac and Windows.

There is the same behavior in Chrome (on Mac and Windows).

Meanwhile, other browsers (even Safari and [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) which are on [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) too) do not jump to the nearest snap point instantly.

It is a bug?

If so, what is the correct place where I can report it? Or what is the correct place (WebKit related) where I can ask about it?

---

```
// Snippet of code required by Stack Overflow to post a question
slider.addEventListener("scroll", _.debounce((e) => {
    const currentHeight = parseFloat(e.target.style["height"]);
    e.target.style["height"] = currentHeight + (flag ? 5 : -5) + "px";
    flag = !flag;
}, 50));
```

Comment: Confirmed it's happening, however I find most of these weird issues have a logical explanation and are not actually bugs. Nevertheless I'll look around. I've had something similar, but not exactly this.

Comment: FYI Chromium derived browsers (incl. Opera) use [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)) which is a fork of WebKit but definitely not the same.

Comment: @Denis Sorry, I did not understand your exact question? When I leave mouse click the box was moving to left or right automatically to align the box with container. Is that the problem or something else?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1181843

Comment: @AbhilashAugustine, if you open inspector, turn on responsive mode, and drag the slider slowly, you will see it bounce back to start over and over.

Comment: The error message is ***"Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code."***.

Comment: *"The problem is described there"*: But the problem should be described ***here***. Both the question and answers are essentially link-only posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Chrome introduced auto-snap after layout changes in M81."* (from *[Scroll snapping after layout changes](https://web.dev/snap-after-layout/)*)

*[Issue 1181843: Scroll-snap jumps to the nearest snap position on repaint in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1181843#c8)*

This behavior is intentional in Chrome, unfortunately.

Comment: Why is this still happening then in responsive mode?

Comment: ```¯\_(ツ)_/¯```